# Balance Of and the amount raised does not increase sender an account

Tags: solidity, remix, balances

Can someone give me a hint or correct what is wrong with the code. Maybe it is obvious where the error is but I do not see it and I'm stuck. What to do next ?.
The code is here:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc3ec072c279043ad2e56f4b5683b78337ed614d9

```
function () payable public {  }

function buy () payable public whenNotPaused beforeDeadline afterStartTime saleNotClosed {
    require(msg.value >= minContribution);

    // Update the sender's balance of wei contributed and the amount raised
    uint amount = msg.value;
    uint currentBalance = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = currentBalance.add(amount);
    amountRaised = amountRaised.add(amount);

    // Compute the number of tokens to be rewarded to the sender
    // Note: it's important for this calculation that both wei
    // and PDT have the same number of decimal places (18)
    uint numTokens = amount.mul(rate);

    // Transfer the tokens from the crowdsale supply to the sender
    if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens)) {
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
        // Check if the funding goal or cap have been reached
        // TODO check impact on gas cost
        checkFundingGoal();
        checkFundingCap();
    }
    else {
        revert();
    }
}
```

what to do to fix it ? (Remix Ropsten does not update a sender balance of).

Any help is very much appreciated.Robert

Comment: Where do you check the updated balance?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Remix to call balanceOf  and the amount rised after I'd sent some ethers to crowdsale contract , but no update of balance. Any a hint ? Robert

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in the fact that the function `function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }` returns a value out of the mapping balances but you are using and updating the mapping named `balanceOf`. You could create a new function that returns `balanceOf[msg.sender]` to check if it works.

Comment: Hello Gabe,
I see You reffering to the line 171 in the contract.(contract BasicToken).
contract ERC20Basic line 125 has got too -function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
If you have something on your mind how the function should looks like please enlightme me !
I'm not programmer.
I tried to add the following line in my buy function;
 balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].add(amount);

Unfortunately without success.